# How do I use an Axios response as a parameter in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise, axios

I'm working on writing a script that will retrieve data from an API. I need to get all instances of the data in the API but the API limits me to 250 results at a time. The response also gives me an offset number which I can use in a new API call to get the next set of results. I know how many calls to the API I need to make and my thought was to use a variable in params so that I could update the offset number after every call to the API. The issue always falls back on actually setting the variable and getting it to be used when the loop runs again.

I am able to run the ajax request and return the data and then set the offset to a variable. I've tried creating an initial API call and then returning the response and then using that returned value in a new function inside of a for loop. That seems like it's the closest solution to me but every time the loop runs, the variable resets to null and I get the initial offset value back.

Here is the most recent code:

```
for (iteration = 1; iteration < 4; iteration++) {
  let offsetValue;
  pullWriteData = offsetValue => {
    return axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "https://api.hubapi.com/engagements/v1/engagements/paged",
      params: {
        hapikey: "API_KEY_HERE",
        limit: 250,
        offset: offsetValue
      }
    }).then(response => {
      return response.data;
    });
  };

  pullWriteData().then(data => {
    offsetValue = data.offset;
    console.log("New offset value: " + offsetValue);
    return offsetValue;
  });
}
```

this code returns:

```
New offset value: 12345678
New offset value: 12345678
New offset value: 12345678
```

I've also built a second Axios call in the `.then` of my pullWriteData() call and that works but that certainly defeats the purpose of writing a program to do that for me.

My expectation is that this will run the initial API call, write the data to a file, update the `offsetValue`, run the API call again with the new `offsetValue`, write that response to a file, update the `offsetValue` and repeat until I've pulled all of the data.

As far as writing the data to a file, I already am able to do that using `fs`. It's just getting the `offsetValue` value to update that seems to be vexing me.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `async/await`, you could do the following with `promises` to ensure you're getting the next `offset` each time and setting it within the loop so the next chained `async` request passes the new `offset` to the request.

**Note:** that with your current iteration, you will only make 3 requests, starting with no `offset=` in the `GET` request, and then the next 2 requests will use the returned `offset` value from the first and second requests respectively, and the 3rd returned `offset` value isn't used as another request isn't made.

```js
const getEngagements = (offsetValue) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "https://api.hubapi.com/engagements/v1/engagements/paged",
      params: {
        hapikey: "demo",
        limit: 250,
        offset: offsetValue
      }
    }).then(response => {
      return resolve(response.data);
    }).catch(error => {
      return reject(error.message)
    })
  })
}

const startPaging = async() => {
  let offsetValue;
  for (let num of [1, 2, 3]) {
    await getEngagements(offsetValue).then((data) => {
      offsetValue = data.offset;
      console.log("New offset value: " + offsetValue);
    })
  }

  /* You could also do a while() loop for while 
   * dataHasMore = true from response data, if you
   * weren't doing a fixed iteration..
   */

  /*
  let dataHasMore = true;
  while (dataHasMore) {
   await getEngagements(offsetValue).then((data) => {
      dataHasMore = data.hasMore;
      offsetValue = data.offset;
      console.log("New offset value: " + offsetValue);
    })
  }
  */

  console.log('Done');
}

startPaging();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was really close to what I had at one point. So close that I'm not quite sure what was missing when I took this route before. I think I wasn't setting offsetValue in the right place. I also really appreciate that you suggested the while loop.

Comment: That looks like the solution I've been hunting. I've got a 1000-record database that wants to return at most 100 results per query, where "page" and "page size" are query parameters. To read all the data, I have to issue repeated queries, incrementing page number, until it answers with 404 to indicate no more pages available. I *think* that your while loop will do the job.

If there's a better way to get the results of these queries concatenated sequentially until the 404 response, we can open another question more specifically for that...

(Not all operations are comfortable as async.)

Comment: (The other suggestions I've seen for this involved recursion, and I don't know/trust enough about Javascript execution to want to bet on that not blowing up memory. In some other languages I'd consider tail recursion an elegant solution.)

Comment: After just a bit of whittling, this seems to be working for me -- at least, it's running the query loop. Now I need to parse the returned data.

(In my case, there is a meta.pagination section which contains page, pages, and count; I can use those in lieu of the dataHasMore test.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can adjust this example for your needs:

```
(async () => {
  const times = Array.from({ length: 4 }, (_, i) => i));
  let offset;

  for (let i of times) {
    offset = await pullWriteData(offset);
  }
})();


function pullWriteData(offsetValue) {
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://api.hubapi.com/engagements/v1/engagements/paged',
    params: {
      hapikey: 'API_KEY_HERE',
      limit: 250,
      offset: offsetValue
    }
  }).then(response => response.data);
}
```